# Array in kotlin : No value passed for parameter array [init]

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, init

This is my **OnboardingActivity**, I'm having an error creating this Array, it is saying that no value was passed in the **int** parameter, I converted this code from ***java to kotlin***, here is the code.

```
class OnboardingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        private var viewPager: ViewPager? = null
        private var btnNext: Button? = null
        private var vectorImage: Array<ImageView>? = null
        private var containerDots: LinearLayout? = null
        private var active: Drawable? = null
        private var inactive: Drawable? = null
        private var adapterFragment: ViewPagerAdapter? = null
        private var lengthSlide: Int = 0
        private var btnSkip: Button? = null


        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(br.com.brq.brqmotors.R.layout.activity_onboarding)
            initViews()
            configSlideAdapter()
            configNextSlideButton()
            configVetorImgSlid()
            configSkipOnboardingButton()
        }

        private fun configSkipOnboardingButton() {
            btnSkip!!.setOnClickListener { finishOnboarding() }
        }

        private fun finishOnboarding() {
            finish()
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, javaClass::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    private fun configVetorImgSlid() {
        lengthSlide = adapterFragment!!.getCount()
        vectorImage = arrayOfNulls<ImageView>(lengthSlide)
        prepareDots()
    }

    private fun prepareDots() {
            for (i in 0 until lengthSlide) {
                vectorImage?.set(i, ImageView(this))
                vectorImage!![i].setImageDrawable(inactive)

                val layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                )
                layoutParams.setMargins(16, 0, 16, 0)
                containerDots!!.addView(vectorImage!![i], layoutParams)
            }
            vectorImage!![0].setImageDrawable(active)
        }
```

**The error is here, more specifically on the line = arrayOfNulls  (lengthSlide)**

```
 private fun configVetorImgSlid() {
     lengthSlide = adapterFragment!!.getCount()
     vectorImage = arrayOfNulls<ImageView>(lengthSlide)
     prepareDots()
 }
```

Comment: You should post the exception you are getting, so it can be analyzed. More often than not the exact cause of the problem is described in the exception message or can be devised from the exception type.

Comment: Based on the information you shared, the cause is extremely likely that your adapterFragment is either null or has 0 count, which means when prepareDots is called it will try to loop over a 0 length array, please add more information about which error is thrown and we will be able to help more

Answer (score 0):

This error shows up when your device is a little slow with Android studio,
`auto correction` gets not called and so reopen or wait a little.